# ArcGIS and ACCESS table

Tags: python, ms-access, arcgis

I'm new to Python in combination with ArcGIS.
I have a shape file with different regions A,B and C and an Access table :

feature region

1 A

1 B

2 C

3 A

3 B

Now I'm trying to select one of the features and corresponding regions to give same a different color. Is there a good way doing this with python? 
Thanks a lot for any idea.

cheers
eactor

Comment: It's a very fuzzy question. Maybe you can explain what you have tried and why that didn't work?

Comment: I try to:
1. I greate a new Table only containing one feature:
arcpy.MakeTableView_management("Tabelle1","Tabelle2","Feature='1'")
2. I can get the number of rows of the new table
arcpy.GetCount_management("Tabelle2")
3. here is the part I miss

Comment: 4. I can select the a region by their names
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("regions", "NEW_SELECTION","NAME='A'")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("regions", "ADD_TO_SELECTION","NAME='B'")
So I need some way to access the names of the regions out of my new created table so I can loop them for my selection? Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you will get more help here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/ Any particular reason why you are doing this in Python? It seems very easy to do using the GUI. Though if you are trying to learn python, I understand

Comment: I'm not trying to learn python, but it i have like 160 regions and over a 1000 features. So doing it by hand would take at least a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it by my own. 
Here are some important hints:

1)Join the table and shape file with the corresponding row:

```
arcpy.AddJoin_management("regionsshape","NAME","region_table","NAME")
```

2)Loop over the table and do selection:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("region_table")
  for row in rows:
     arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("regionsshape","NEW_SELECTION","FEATURE_NAME='" + row.getValue("NAME") + "'")
```

now you only have to include what you want to do with the selection in my case produce a layer file:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("regions",row.getValue("id"))  
  arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(row.getValue("id"),"C:/temp/"+row.getValue("id")e+".lyr","ABSOLUTE")
```